# Silverlight repeat behavior in visual state

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, animation

I have visual state = loading. And i need in this visual state show loading circle with always repeated animation. But it repeats only once! How can i set repeat behavior to forever??

```
        <VisualState x:Name="LoadingChildNodes">
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.915" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Duration="0:0:2" To="360" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution :)

```
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="360"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```